# Woocommerce REST User Login Authentication

Tags: angularjs, rest, woocommerce

I am building a mobile app using Ionic Framework. I have a woocommerce website already set up and running, since a few months. Now I need to allow my users to login to the app using the user credentials they have registered with in the website. I am using the WP-API to return the JSON data from the website, but it follows a complex procedure for authentication as described [here](http://wp-api.org/guides/authentication.html).

However, the documentation doesn't give any idea about how to retrieve the user details asscoiated with the account, like the address, phone number etc. Any leads on this front would be appreciated.

Comment: If you don;t mind using a plugin, give the following plugin a try : [REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/)

Comment: Hey Anand, I don't mind using a plugin, if it really solves the problem. Will this allow me to access the user details?

Comment: Moreover, I have already specified that I am already using WP-API and this seems to be the same, if i am not wrong.

Comment: Yes, that is the same plugin you are already using... and that should end up in WordPress 4.4 core. User information is covered in the [WooCommerce API Docs](http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#customers-properties)

Comment: Ah yes, indeed its the same plugin, my bad

Comment: You need to [modify the response](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/modifying/) to include extra user meta. By default it will not include extra user metadata ( phone, address etc ) which is added by WooCommerce.

Comment: So that brings us back to the question! :-(